# Apple music genre selection balls/bubbles control UI (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, box2d

I was trying to create an apple music genre selection control on Android. I can see people on stack has asked this question. I have found the similar control on iOS, which makes use of SpriteKit and was wondering what's the best way to proceed with it. Can someone provide some insight here?

I have tried physics engine for this, but I'm not sure if I am on a right path or not. I have used box2d for a while to achieve this but not much of help.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Reno Jones

Comment: I was able to do it with libGdx+OpenGL. :)

Comment: Would you post a source code or tutorial??